# Possible bug in SciPy shgo (Unexpected TypeError)

Tags: scipy, scipy-optimize, shgo

When running the following

```
from scipy.optimize import rosen, rosen_der, rosen_hess
bounds = [(0,1.6), (0, 1.6), (0, 1.4), (0, 1.4), (0, 1.4)]
result = scipy.optimize.shgo(rosen, bounds, options={'jac':rosen_der,'hess':rosen_hess})
```

I get

```
TypeError: _minimize_slsqp() got multiple values for argument 'jac'
```

I believe that `jac` is correctly specified here (see [this documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.shgo.html#scipy.optimize.shgo)). Did I make a mistake or is there a bug here?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug see https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/14533.
(An answer with a workaround would still be much appreciated.)